# Print composer layout without opening project in GUI (no iface solution)

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, printing, layouts

I would like to print some composers without open the files that contains them in QGIS.

- without using templates
- not using `iface`
- using,

  ```
  app = QgsApplication(sys.argv, gui_flag)    
  app.initQgis()    
  project.read(QFileInfo(project_path))
  ```
- for QGIS 2.18.x (then I can't use [QgsLayoutManager](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutManager.html))

How can I call a composer without `iface` and layout manager?